# How to clone a GCP VM instance boot disk, read/write from/to it and re-attach it

Tags: google-compute-engine

Although I'm sure the overall operation can be accomplished, see [detach and re-attach part](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk) for example, it might not be possible to do that as just one, let's say, operation.

The use case here is, a RHEL image boots into emergency mode and root access is disabled, or some other issue that makes it so that you can't enter the machine now, but with operations on the file system this could be fixed (edit fstab for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `instance0` won't boot.
We'll need a second instance (`instance1`) to attach and mount the boot disk of `instance0`.
Assuming both instances are in the same zone (modify accordingly), let's set  some variables:

```
project= #TODO fill
zone= #TODO fill
instance0= #TODO fill
instance1= #TODO fill
instance0_bootdisk=$(gcloud compute instances describe $instance0 --format "value(disks[0].deviceName)")
instance0_bootdisk_snapshot=$instance0_bootdisk"-snapshot"
instance0_bootdisk_clone=$instance0_bootdisk_snapshot"-disk"
instance1_mntdev="/dev/sdb1"
instance1_mntpath="/mnt/clone"
```

We're assuming that `instance1` has only only one disk attached to it (the boot disk), so `/dev/sdb1` works (modify accordingly).

For convenience, issue:

```
gcloud config set project $project
gcloud config set compute/zone $zone
```

To get the proceedings proceeding, let's stop `instance0`, create a snapshot of its boot disk, detach the boot disk and create a new disk from the mentioned snapshot:

```
gcloud compute instances stop $instance0

gcloud compute disks snapshot $instance0_bootdisk --snapshot-names $instance0_bootdisk_snapshot --zone $zone

gcloud compute instances detach-disk $instance0 --device-name $instance0_bootdisk

gcloud compute disks create $instance0_bootdisk_clone --source-snapshot $instance0_bootdisk_snapshot
```

Now, we attach the newly created disk as a data disk to the `instance1`, rw mount it, write to it, unmount it, and optionally detach it

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk $instance1 --disk $instance0_bootdisk_clone --device-name $instance0_bootdisk_clone

gcloud compute ssh $instance1 --command "sudo mkdir -p $instance1_mntpath && sudo mount $instance1_mntdev $instance1_mntpath"

gcloud compute ssh $instance1  -- sudo vi $instance1_mntpath/etc/fstab" #for example
gcloud compute scp $instance1:/var/log/syslog . #for another example 

gcloud compute ssh $instance1 --command "sudo umount $instance1_mntpath"

gcloud compute instances detach-disk $instance1 --device-name $instance0_bootdisk_clone #not mandatory
```

Finally we attach the modified version of the created disk as the boot disk to `instance0` in the hopes that the operating system boots.

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk $instance0 --disk $instance0_bootdisk_clone --device-name $instance0_bootdisk --boot

gcloud compute instances start $instance0 #wait for completion
gcloud compute ssh $instance0 --command "ps 1"
```